# XPath issue when doing XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am stuck with this issue for 2days. All i wanted to extract the data marked in the image to be transformed by a XSLT. I have given the XML file in this question too. Sorry if this seems to be a really dumb question. Similar paths like //PartyInformation/Buyer/Contact//Name works in the document. But //PartyInformation/Buyer/Contact//Name is not working

So far i have tried,

- //PartyInformation/Buyer/Contact/Name[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHQ2H.png)
- //PartyInformation/Buyer/Contact//Name
- /Invoice[@xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"]/PartyInformation[@xmlns=""]/Buyer/Contact[@xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema"]/Name[@xmlns=""]/text()

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you.

[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Invoice xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema">
    <InvoiceHeader xmlns="">
        <InvoiceDate />
        <InvoiceDueDate />
        <InvoiceNo />
        <AllowDuplicates>false</AllowDuplicates>
        <AddAttachment>false</AddAttachment>
        <UserApprovedSubmission>false</UserApprovedSubmission>
        <SellerOrderNumber />
        <PurchaseOrderNumber />
        <NumberOfLines>1</NumberOfLines>
        <InvoiceType>
            <Type>ServiceInvoice</Type>
        </InvoiceType>
        <SourceInvoiceType>
            <Type>ServiceInvoice</Type>
        </SourceInvoiceType>
        <DeliveryInformation>
            <DeliveryInstructions />
        </DeliveryInformation>
    </InvoiceHeader>
    <PartyInformation xmlns="">
        <Seller>
            <Party xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema">
                <PartyId xmlns="" />
                <ExternalSystemId xmlns="" />
                <Name xmlns="" />
                <GBN xmlns="" />
            </Party>
            <Address xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema" />
        </Seller>
        <Buyer>
            <Party xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema">
                <PartyId xmlns="">2</PartyId>
                <ExternalSystemId xmlns="" />
                <Name xmlns="" />
                <GBN xmlns="" />
            </Party>
            <Address xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema" />
            <Contact xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema">
                <Name xmlns="">Mr Parminder Singh</Name>
                <Phone xmlns="" />
                <Fax xmlns="" />
                <Email xmlns="" />
            </Contact>
            <SuppliersCustomerId />
        </Buyer>
        <ShipTo>
            <Party xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema">
                <Name xmlns="" />
            </Party>
            <Address xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema" />
        </ShipTo>
        <ShipFrom>
            <Party xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema">
                <Name xmlns="" />
            </Party>
            <Address xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema" />
        </ShipFrom>
        <Payer>
            <Party xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema">
                <Name xmlns="" />
            </Party>
            <Address xmlns="http://Companydomain.Schema" />
        </Payer>
    </PartyInformation>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: Search for "XSLT default namespace". Someone asks this question nearly every day, and there are lots of good answers. To prevent the waste of two days on such problems in future, I suggest spending 10 minutes a day looking at all the XSLT questions raised on SO: you will learn a great deal and save a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Contact` node is under the `http://Companydomain.Schema` namespace. Try:

```
//PartyInformation/Buyer/*[local-name()='Contact']/Name
```

or, you can register the namespace in the xslt,

```
xmlns:com="http://Companydomain.Schema"
```

and have the xpath

```
//PartyInformation/Buyer/com:Contact/Name
```